# Is there a way to add a Dimension or Metric to an existing BigQuery View?

Tags: view, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to find a way with BigQuery to add a new dimension [called 'Creative'] to an existing View. I also want this updated View to be reflected in my DataStudio dashboard.

The following is what I know / tried with certainty:

- The Table that the View references has been updated and reflects the new field
- I ran a query to update the View with the newly added field to the Table
- When I query the now updated View, the new field shows up
- Regardless of the point above, the new field is not showing up in the View's schema
- The new field is not available in Data Studio with my updated View

I wouldn't mind simply deleting the View and re-establishing it with the new schema, but then I will lose all my DataStudio connections, calculated fields, etc.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

```
Select Date, Year, Cal_Mth, Cal_Wk, b.Brand as Brand, b.Site as Platform, 
b.Tactic as Tactic, b.category as Category, 
b.message as Message, b.offer as Offer, b.Creative as Creative, 
b.Campaign as Campaign, b.Audience as Audience,
Campaign_Name,
sum(c.YT_Cost) as Spend,
sum(a.Impressions) as Impr,
sum(a.Clicks) as Clicks,
sum(c.YT_Views) as Views_,
from icrossingdatastorage.BSRO_MediaDB.DCMtableV2 as A
inner join (select ( Replace(Placement_Name,"_____","")) as 
Placement_Name, Campaign_Key as Campaign_Name, Creative_Key as Creative, 
Audience_Key as Audience_Name,
Brand, Tactic, Category_ as category, Message, Offer, Site, Campaign, 
Audience from icrossingdatastorage.BSRO_MediaDB.DCM_Naming_Template) B
on a.Placement = b.Placement_Name
inner join (select Date as Day, Ad_group, ( Replace(Campaign," Feb","")) 
as Campaign,
sum(Cost) as YT_Cost, sum(Views) as YT_Views, avg(Watch_time) as 
YT_Watch_time, sum(Store_Visits) as YT_Store_Visits from 
icrossingdatastorage.BSRO_MediaDB.GoogleAds_OLV2 group by 1,2,3) C
on b.Campaign_Name = c.Campaign
and b.Audience_Name = c.Ad_Group
and a.Date = c.Day
Group By 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
Order By 1 Asc
```

There are no 'errors' or 'error messages' but I would like to find some solution of adding this field to my View without having to delete and re-establish my existing View connected to Data Studio..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement to replace the view
2. Confirm in the BigQuery UI that the schema reflects the new column.
3. Reconnect to the view in Data Studio to pick up the new columns.

You don't need to delete the connection in Data Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! BQ wasn't recognizing the 'create or replace view' as a function, but I simply dropped the View then reran the new query and saved it as the same view name - the schema now recognizes the new field and the Data Studio connection is fine. However, Data Studio is not recognizing the new field and there's no reconnect option for me to update the data set that will work including refreshing the data set.. Is there some other way to force Data Studio to recognize the added field..?

Comment: You need to find the data source from the home page of Data Studio, select it, and then reconnect...

Comment: It actually seems be a permissions issue - Even though I am a co-owner of these data sources, reconnecting them is apparently the one thing I am unable to do.. I can edit fields, create calculations, etc. I was fortunately able to copy the sources which have all the custom created fields, but all the charts, scorecards, etc. in DS will have to be switched. Otherwise, your answer works, thanks!